# Auto creating artboards in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, batch-processing, artboard

I have an Illustrator file with icons set up in this fashion on one artboard.
[image: Icon Set]

Is there a way for me to create artboards for each icon for export easily, without going in and having to click each icon?

Comment: Are each one of those icons in its own separate layer or group?

Comment: They'e all on one main layer, but the different parts of each icon are grouped

Comment: `Release to Layers (Sequence)` then... https://forums.adobe.com/message/4757712#4757712

Answer (score 3):

It's really easy. Calculate the distance between each icon, and the size of each one. Then go to the Artboard palette and add the amount of artboards according to the numbers of icons that you have. Reorganize the artboards through the menu: Object → Artboard → Rearrange. Specify the columns and the distance of each artboards to fit in every single icon.

Answer (score 1):

There's a script that can creat an artboard from each layer, if you can get each icon into its own layer:
[Make artboards from layers script](https://github.com/michaelchaize/appliness/blob/master/Illustrator-create-artboards/CreateArtboardsLayers.jsx)